# Non-blocking Runonce Entry?

Tags: windows-7, registry, installation

We have multi-part install that needs a reboot to continue.

We added a RunOnce entry under HKLM to automatically re-launch "setup.exe" after a reboot.

One quirky result of adding setup.exe to RunOnce is that "Windows Shell" won't load until setup.exe terminates.

How can we make Windows continue to load "Windows Shell" even if setup.exe has not yet terminated?

PS: We can't make use of the Run key because of [elevation blocking](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/uac/archive/2006/08/23/715265.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: ok you want to load your "setup.exe" after everything is loaded and so it doesnt block the other services from being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is put your "setup.exe" at this HKCU this will let you setup.exe run
and wont block `"Windows Shell"` from loading

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

and in your case

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Comment: I can't use the RUN key because of the elevation blocking.